# Dig resolves a domain, but all other programs fail to find it

Tags: macos, network, dns

Mac OS X Mavericks, no VPN, connecting via wifi.

This domain resolves to my IP address in the local network

```
$> dig mydomain.xx
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.xx.    3591    IN  A   192.168.10.18
```

I tested it on several computers and the resolution is correct, works with `host` and `nslookup` as well.

However, when using chrome, curl, ping, traceroute, or any other tool that will actually try to connect to the ip, it hangs and eventually fails.

pinging `192.168.10.18` works of course.

From another computer it works but it does not work from mine.

We have other domains that behave the same way for my coworkers, everything work except the access to my domain from my machine.

I'm using dnsmasq to catch all domains in .dev, but even with that disabled it still fails.

We use google dns as provided by our DHCP server.

What could cause the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Found it, it was a misconfiguration issue.

An old pow config file stayed in /etc/resolver, forcing the nameserver to be 127.0.0.1 for this domain.

Comment: I had the same problem from when I stopped using `dnsmasq`. I had forgotten I had placed the files there. Thought I'd comment to mention `dnsmasq` specifically in case people search for that.